# Combobox com sim e não no laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou com um combobox que tem os valores sim e não. Ele está trazendo o valor não que coloquei no banco mas no formulário de editar não aparece a outra opção que no caso seria o sim. Como faço para a opção contrária aparecer?

```
<select name="disponivel_venda" class="form-control">
    @foreach($properties as $value)
        <option {{$property->disponivel_venda == $value->disponivel_venda ? 'selected' : '' }}  value="{{ $value->disponivel_venda }}">{{$value->disponivel_venda}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Como está sendo gravado?

Comment: <select name="disponivel_venda" class="form-control">
             <option selected="disabled">Selecionar</option>
             <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
             <option value="Não">Não</option>
</select>

Comment: Ele causa qual problema?

Comment: Falei ai em cima na postagem

Comment: Acredito que o seu Controller de envio seria necessário para mim ver o que está enviando para View e me parece um ajuste simples já visto que esse select só tem duas opções, só preciso mesmo saber qual das classes volta esse valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente seria isso:

```
<select name="disponivel_venda" class="form-control">
    <option {{$property->disponivel_venda=='Sim'?' selected':''}}>Sim</option>
    <option {{$property->disponivel_venda!='Sim'?' selected':''}}>Não</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Deu certo, era exatamente isso, obrigado.